# Mysql convert time to sec then insert into table

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

using the command : `SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(timing) FROM chrono`

I would like to convert the `timing` column format from `hh:mm:ss` to `seconds` then insert results into another table  called `timing_in_seconds`.

could you please help achieve this operation?

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get? The question is a bit unclear, at least to me

Comment: @Mureinik Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: are we to understand that `timing` is a `varchar` column?

Comment: @Mureinik Thank you for the feedback.
the 'timing' column contain TIME data in TIME Format. i have to convert hh:mm:ss into seconds then sum this column with another column containing the same TIME Format to find the timing difference. this action is required for 1000 stored ID.

Comment: @ADyson I am using TIME format for the 'timing' column.

Comment: Seems like maybe this would help you then? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec . I never used it but I found it on google in a few moments...did you not search for anything before now?

Comment: yes, I have tried but as I am not familar with Mysql queries, i asked for help :)

Comment: well I appreciate that obviously but familiar or not you can at least research and make some attempt. If you tried, show us what you tried and explain what went wrong. Perhaps it's nearly right and we can fix it for you instead of simply spoon-feeding a solution

Comment: @ADyson thanks i'm GMT

Comment: As in the timezone? Not sure what you mean or how it's relevant

Answer (score 2):

You can use `select and insert` method for this purpose.

```
INSERT INTO timing_in_seconds(seconds) SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(timing) FROM chrono
```

**EDIT**

-- for updating particular record instead of insert if the record is already exist --

```
INSERT INTO timing_in_seconds(seconds, uniqueColumn)
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(c.timing), c.uniqueValueForEachRecord FROM chrono c
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE seconds=TIME_TO_SEC(c.timing)
```

Comment: Many thanks Janaka,
 
your query works like a charm, but the values are inserted into new lines in my table.  is there any way to make the convertion related to each value for each convertion performed ?

ID, name, timing, timing_in_seconds.
0,xxxx,hh:mm:ss, 0000

I appreciate your help.

Comment: yes you can use `on duplicate key update` method for this but you need to make some column or combination of column to be unique on the `timing_in_seconds` table. Then if that key is already exist on the table then it will update given columns or else it will insert all values as a new record. Updated the answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

Made the changes in the answer as per comment reference:  codeshare.io/aJzj4X

**Edit:**

Here is the query that you can use to calculate seconds and sum functions.

```
INSERT INTO chrono(ID, name, timing1, timing2) 
VALUES(0001, 'john', '00:02:00', '00:02:00');

UPDATE chrono 
SET timing1_in_seconds = TIME_TO_SEC(timing1), 
timing2_in_seconds = TIME_TO_SEC(timing2),
total_time = ADDTIME(timing1, timing2)
WHERE ID = 0001;
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Hi, 
Many thanks for the replay. the issue is with the insertion of the result into the table

Comment: Please provide your db table schema with clear details so that we can help you with right column queries.

Comment: Great !! Thank you ! what function do i have to implement to make it affect all rows ? my table contain about 400 entry.

Comment: if you remove `where` clause mentioned in the `update` query as  mentioned in the answer and then execute it then it will add data for all the rows in your table.  `UPDATE chrono 
SET timing1_in_seconds = TIME_TO_SEC(timing1), 
timing2_in_seconds = TIME_TO_SEC(timing2),
total_time = ADDTIME(timing1, timing2)`